# UPDATED: $.each to match element ID to add/remove class fails after first run

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Storing ID values in localStorage and to match the values with an element ID to add/remove a class.

My problem is the match works correctly the first time the page is shown (applies a class when there is a match, ignores when no match). But, after a page that has a match is shown and the class is applied subsequent views of pages that don't have a match show the class is applied incorrectly.

Here is the portion of the code that is causing my grief.

```
follows = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('follows')) || [];


$.each(follows, function(key, value) {

    alert(value);
    if (value === $('a.followButtonPage').attr("id")) {
        alert('matched: ' + value);

        $('a[id="' + value + '"]').removeClass("follow").addClass("unfollow");
    }

});
```

I am running the code on a pageshow and wrapped in a function (that supposed to wait until DOM is fully loaded):

```
  $(document).on("pageshow", "#archive",  function(e) {
  $( function() { …
```

Thanks in advance for help and guidance. Open to completely different approaches—anything that fixes this.

UPDATE: The code recommended below (albeit a better approach) causes the same behavior (so still searching for a resolution.

```
$.each(follows, function(key, value) {
    $('#' + value ).removeClass("follow").addClass("unfollow");
});
```

Comment: This question is not very clear, the context is pretty vague

Comment: `.attr()` will only return the attribute of the first element in a collection, so if there are more elements that match `a.followButtonPage` selector you're comparing `value` to the `id` of the first one in every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

That conditional not only doesn't check what you probably want, it's just completely unnecessary.  All you need is this:

```
$.each(follows, function(key, value) {
    $('#' + value ).removeClass("follow").addClass("unfollow");
});
```

Since you're targeting elements by ID `$('#' + value )` is enough, as ID should be unique in the document. And checking if there's a matching element is done implicitly by jQuery, so it'll silently do nothing if there's no match.

Comment: Thanks, will try shortly.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the results as with the original code including first time correct plus page refresh corrects.

Comment: Clarification:The first execution (always applies class correctly) is then applied to all subsequent page shows (with different IDs) whether it is a "correct" result or not.